Fluid Jet Hitting Inclined Plate

The force $F$ labelled in the diagram only comes about due to the $x$-component of $V_1$. Why do we not consider the $y$-component of $V_1$? Intuition tells me that there would be a force in the $y$-component, therefore a force only in the $x$-component is not sufficient to hold the plate stationary.
There is an explanation that since $\theta =45^\circ$, the symmetry of the configuration makes it such that $V_2 = V_3$ and mass flow rate at $2$ and $3$ would be equal as well. Why is this so? As if I were to imagine spraying a hose at a inclined plate similar to the above configuration, more fluid would flow in the direction of $V_2$.
When I first attempted the question, I did not rotate the reference axes as shown in the photo. I just took reference axis as upwards and rightwards. Using linear momentum, I got $F_x = \dot M \ V_1 - 0;$ (zero since we are assuming that the forces cancel each other out at the exit due to symmetry). I did the same for $F_y$, which gave me just $0$ as at the entrance of the control volume, there is no $y$-component velocity, and the forces cancel each other out at the exit as well. Therefore, by Pythagoras theorem, $F$ would just be $F = F_x = \rho A_1 \ V_1^2$, instead of $\rho A_1 V_1 (V_1 \sin \theta)$ when the reference axes were rotated. What am I doing wrong as should they not result in the same answer?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

V2 and V3 are not necessarily equal.

There would be a force in the y-direction if the fluid was viscous. The question probably assumes otherwise.
